# Correctly instantiating a DRF ModelField

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am trying to use ModelField to serialize a JSONField. I am not quite sure what is the expected thing to be passed into 'model_field' kwarg. Passing the class name doesn't cut it since the ModelField seems to be storing the 'model_field' directly and calling methods on that.

```
== restapi.py ==

    reading_order = ModelField(model_field=JSONField) # Corresponds to a JSONField 'reading_order' in my model.

== rest_framework/fields.py ModelField ==

def field_to_native(self, obj, field_name):
    value = self.model_field._get_val_from_obj(obj)
```

This results in error saying that first argument should be an instance to JSONField which makes sense since self.model_field is the class definition. If I change it to:

```
def field_to_native(self, obj, field_name):
    value = self.model_field._get_val_from_obj(obj._meta.get_field(field_name), obj)
```

It works fine.

I am not sure if this is a bug I have stumbled upon or if I am instantiating the ModelField wrong. Can someone please point me to right way to use ModelField?

Regards,
Abhaya

Comment: Facing the save issue, is there a working solution?

Comment: The second snippet above works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Believe that's a docs issue.  `ModelField` should be passed a field instance, not a field class, so you should instantiate the model field like so:

```
 reading_order = ModelField(model_field=JSONField())
```

Comment: This is the right direction. It seems we need to extract the field instance from the model otherwise Django throws an error. If you update your answer, I will accept it.